# Break an in-memory ZipFile for unittests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a script, which takes an in-memory ZipFile, unzips files contained in it, and then saves them in a dictionary under 'filename': io.bytesIO() key-value structure.

I would like to write a unittest, which checks script's behaviour in a situation, when this in-memory ZipFile object is corrupted. However, I cannot find any tutorials on how to mock a corrupted data like that.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: How does the script get the "in-memory ZipFile"? Through a function call?

Comment: Yes, through a function which reads in some files from a disc, packs them into a io.BytesIO object, and then compresses it with a ZipFile object.

Comment: Then why not just generate an `io.bytesIO()` full with random bytes?

Comment: Unpacking of the zipfile with that bytesIO object would have to fail. I am not sure of how to code what you have mentioned.

Comment: Why don't you put in some snippets of code to illustrate your problem.